# Sci Fi 80’s comic book where three space warriors competed for a prize

Tags: story-identification, comics

In the mid 80’s I read a comic book about a competition where three space warriors competed for a prize from a queen.

The main character was human. Each warrior faced their own challenge.

The human made it through the competition.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Valérian & Laureline: *Heroes of the Equinox***

This story, originally published in 1978 as *Les Héros de l’équinoxe*, has exactly this plot, except there were four heroes (including Valérian). The prize is becoming the father of a new line of beings.

[Description](https://theslingsandarrows.com/valerian-and-laureline-heroes-of-the-equinox/):

> Valerian is selected to represent Earth in a contest run by the Grand Council of Simlane, where he’ll be joined by the champions of three other worlds. Simlane is a dying society with an unusual and secret process of replenishing the population that’s not been working of late. Formerly chosen heroes would set sail for a distant land and overcome hardships. They’d return several days later with little memory of what occurred, and several boats with young children to increase the head count. Lately, though, the selected champions haven’t been returning, and the older citizens no longer have the strength to maintain the magnificent structures at the heart of their tourist based economy.

[image]

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! 
Can’t believe you knew this. 
That’s was my Moby Dick search for years.